# Adding 100 to values of an Array that are divisible by 3 using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am trying to add 100 to values of an array that are divisible by 3. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
```

];

```
test.forEach(function(i){
if(i % 3 === 0){
test.splice(0, 1, i+100);           
}

});
```

Comment: Why is it `i % 3` ifyour description said 100?

Answer (score 1):

At the first place you are missing to move index, it is always 0

```
test.forEach(function(i, ind){
  if(i % 3 === 0){
    test.splice(ind, 1, i+100);           
  }
});
```

at the second place splice it is not very effective way to use this problem, much easier

```
test = test.map(i => i % 3 == 0 ? i + 100 : i)
```

or if you want to change in place then

```
test.forEach(function(i, ind){
  if(i % 3 === 0) test(ind) = i+100;           
});
```

at the third place in title you wrote divisible by 100 but in code i % 3, please correct

Comment: thank you. This is an assignment that specifically requires forEach, rather than map. I'll give this a try. Thank you